# How to override handler404 and handler505 error in django?

Tags: python, django

How do i override the  handler404 and handler505 error in django? i already change the **DEBUG TRUE** into False in my settings.py.

this is my views.py

```
def Errorhandler404(request):
    return render(request, 'customAdmin/my_custom_page_not_found_view.html', status=404)

def Errorhandler500(request):
    return render(request, 'customAdmin/my_custom_error_view.html', status=500)
```

this is my urls.py

```
handler404 = customAdmin.views.Errorhandler404
handler500 = customAdmin.views.Errorhandler500
urlpatterns = [
     .....
]
```

this is the error

[image]

this is the documentation i follow

https://micropyramid.com/blog/handling-custom-error-pages-in-django/

Comment: If that's all your custom error handlers do, then it would be easier to rename your error templates to `404.html` and 500.html`. That way, Django will use your custom templates, and you don't need to set `handler404` or `handler500`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a function that takes the `exception` parameter into account as well, as specified in the [documentation on **`handler404`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#handler404):

> **`handler404`**
>
> A callable, or a string representing the full Python import path to
> the view that should be called if none of the URL patterns match.
>
> By default, this is django.views.defaults.page_not_found(). If you
> implement a custom view, be **sure it accepts `request` and
> `exception` arguments** and **returns an `HttpResponseNotFound`**.

You can ignore the parameter, or print information about the exception in the response:

```
def Errorhandler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'customAdmin/my_custom_page_not_found_view.html', status=404)

def Errorhandler500(request):
    return render(request, 'customAdmin/my_custom_error_view.html', status=500)
```

Normally the `ErrorHandler404` should return a [**`HttpResponseNotFound`** response [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotFound):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.template import loader

def Errorhandler404(request, exception):
    content = loader.render_to_string('customAdmin/my_custom_page_not_found_view.html', {}, request)
    return HttpResponseNotFound(content)
```

The `ErrorHandler500` should return a [**`HttpResponseServerError`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseServerError):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError
from django.template import loader

def Errorhandler500(request):
    content = loader.render_to_string('customAdmin/my_custom_page_not_found_view.html', {}, request)
    return HttpResponseServerError(content)
```

Comment: ?: (urls.E007) The custom handler500 view 'customAdmin.views.Errorhandler500' does not take the correct number of arguments (request).

Comment: @marvin: yes, it is only the 404 handler :).

Comment: how about 500 handler?

Comment: @marvin: this only takes a `request`. But both functions need to respond with other objects than the `HttpResponse` object, see edited answer.